# ImageButtons does not Render Over a Fragment Map

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following problem im trying to put three ImageButtons over a Fragment Map so i have the following xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mauricio.fastmark.Home">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mauricio.fastmark.Home" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mark_btn"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_profile"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_mark"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_btn"
    android:id="@+id/btn_profile"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_mark" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_consult_btn"
    android:id="@+id/btn_consult"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_profile"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_mark" />
```

At this point It's okay because in the [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS9L3.png) It shows the Fragment (in gray color because some warnings) with the three ImageButtons over the fragment like I want, but when I [run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyUJZ.png) the app It's just rendering a small part of the ImageButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised that when I was picking the image with this line: app:srcCompat="@drawable/image" it didnt work, but now I'm using this : android:src="@drawable/image" and It shows the buttons perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try  putting Map inside a Framelayout.// as Framelayout draws everything on top of each other

```
<Framelayout
     ....
      ....>
  <fragment>  //Fragment is drawn First
  <RelativeLayout>
      <imageButtons>
       ..
       ..
   </RelativeLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solve my problem, I guess the map fragment renders first, but I dont know why the imagebuttons renders like that.